# Validate configuration file on Worker Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, service, worker

I would like to validate the data of appsettings.json file of my Worker Service.
I've implemented [Options Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1), and I need to inject a class for a complex validation, so I should use code like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MyConfigOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(
                                        MyConfigOptions.MyConfig));
    services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IValidateOptions
                              <MyConfigOptions>, MyConfigValidation>());
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

The problem is that I can't use `services.AddControllersWithViews()`, because Worker Service template doesn't reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc namespace.
Is there another way to implement Options Pattern with file validation? Maybe also installing other Nuget packages...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,Worker Service cannot use `services.AddControllersWithViews();`.If you want to use validation,you can validate the file data in worker.cs.

Here is a demo worked.The file validated in the constructor of Worker,and `Worker.cs` is singleton.So in the demo the file validates once when the life of `Worker.cs` starts:

Appsettiing.js:

```
    {
  "MyConfig": {
    "Key1": "My Key One",
    "Key2": 10000,
    "Key3": 32
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureLogging(loggerFactory => loggerFactory.AddEventLog())
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    });
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions<MyConfigOptions>()
            .Bind(Configuration.GetSection(MyConfigOptions.MyConfig))
            .ValidateDataAnnotations();
        services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IValidateOptions
                          <MyConfigOptions>, MyConfigValidation>());
    }
```

Worker.cs:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IOptions<MyConfigOptions> _config;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IOptions<MyConfigOptions> config)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            _logger.LogInformation("Key2: " + _config.Value.Key2 , DateTimeOffset.Now);


            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

MyConfigOptions.cs:

```
public class MyConfigOptions
{
    public const string MyConfig = "MyConfig";

    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public int Key2 { get; set; }

    public int Key3 { get; set; }
}
```

MyConfigValidation.cs：

```
public MyConfigOptions _config { get; private set; }

    public MyConfigValidation(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config.GetSection(MyConfigOptions.MyConfig)
            .Get<MyConfigOptions>();
    }

    public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string name, MyConfigOptions options)
    {
        string vor = null;
        var rx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$");
        var match = rx.Match(options.Key1);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Value))
        {
            vor = $"{options.Key1} doesn't match RegEx \n";
        }

        if (options.Key2 < 0 || options.Key2 > 1000)
        {
            vor = $"{options.Key2} doesn't match Range 0 - 1000 \n";
        }

        if (_config.Key2 != default)
        {
            if (_config.Key3 <= _config.Key2)
            {
                vor += "Key3 must be > than Key2.";
            }
        }

        if (vor != null)
        {
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(vor);
        }

        return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
    }
```

Result:
[image]